# Porque no carga ng-select?

Tags: html, angular, frontend

Estoy queriendo usar la libreria Ng-Select en Angular ejecute el
`npm i @ng-select/ng-select`

Importe en el module.ts
`import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';`

Y lo declare dentro de los imports.

En el HTML tengo esto:

```
<ng-select [items]="options" 
           [multiple]="true" 
           bindLabel="label" 
           bindValue="value"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedValues"
           [searchable]="true">
</ng-select>
```

Y en el TS

```
options = [  { value: 'option1', label: 'Option 1' },  { value: 'option2', label: 'Option 2' },  { value: 'option3', label: 'Option 3' },];
  selectedValues: any[] = [];
```

Y en el navegador el unico error que aparece es el siguiente:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'firstCreatePass')

Comment: Algo que sirve: coloca ese ng-select dentro de un div con un ngIf y le asignas una variable booleana, la inicializas como false y una vez que llegues al ngOnInit la defines como true.

Comment: ¿Buscaste donde se hace uso de `firstCreatePass` en tu código?